# Combine two lists in a pythonic way

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

I have no clue how to search for this, however, I cannot find an obvious solution for my pythonic problem. I would like to combine two lists (one is a manipulated one of the other) and permute them by keeping the length of the lists constant.

An example:

```
a = ['A','B','C','D']
b = ['a','b','c','d']

combined = [['a','B','C','D'], ['A','b','C','D'], ..., ['a','b','c','d']]
```

And then I can permute them using itertools. However, the first step is for me not easy to manage. I don't want nested for-loops and Co.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ['A','B','C','D']
>>> b = ['a','b','c','d']  # [x.lower() for x in a]
>>> [list(x) for x in itertools.product(*zip(a, b))]
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'd'], ['A', 'B', 'c', 'D'],
 ['A', 'B', 'c', 'd'], ['A', 'b', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'b', 'C', 'd'],
 ['A', 'b', 'c', 'D'], ['A', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
 ['a', 'B', 'C', 'd'], ['a', 'B', 'c', 'D'], ['a', 'B', 'c', 'd'],
 ['a', 'b', 'C', 'D'], ['a', 'b', 'C', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'D'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']]
```

Comment: You are my genius! Thanks so much. What does *zip mean?

Comment: @anki, `zip(a, b)` will return `[('A', 'a'), ('B', 'b'), ('C', 'c'), ('D', 'd')]` in Python 2.x. (returns a corresponding iterator in Python 3.x). For more information about each functions, please follow the links in the answer.